# Contract expiration dates vs using mined block number

Tags: solidity

If I want a bunch of contracts to expire at the same time, say all expire at March 30th, 12pm, is it possible to do this? Or is it much more secure to say they expire at block number X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some info here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25170/how-to-do-a-contract-with-expire-time. It looks like the timestamp can be manipulated, so you should avoid using that.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/solidity-timestamp-dependency-is-it-possible-to-do-safely/15049

Comment: Add relevant explanation along with links as the links may turn obsolete in future